# How to know PHP is set-up correctly for Apache on localhost?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL for a flash application via PHP, but I am having trouble connecting to the server. I created the following .php to test whether it is functioning correctly:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE testphp",$link))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try and access this from my browser I don't get anything back, it just remains blank? (when I just do localhost/xxx.php is just displays the code, don't know if that's helpful? -aside from entering file path) I tried some other .php files, but I either just get an error back or white web browser screen, as above? How can I test to see whether PHP is setup correctly? I know for sure it is working when I login using the mysql shell and do "show databases;" and testphp is listed, it is currently not. Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

Turns out that I had been using the installer while I think there were a lot of assumptions that I was using binaries (or vice versa). Anyhow I have it up and running...expletive, expletive! :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: What sort of error messages are you getting?  Have you tried a simpler script, like `<?php echo "hello world"; ?>`

Comment: make sure you have error_reporting set to a level suitable for development, such as E_ALL or E_ALL|E_STRICT, and make sure display_errors is enabled.

Comment: @Oli I still get a blank screen if I run that code?

Comment: Can you see some source code in you blank page? (view source) Are you perhaps getting the php code in your browser.

Comment: Check your server's error_log. PHP tends to default to NOT displaying errors on fresh installs, so the server error log is the only place where details of the problem will get stored.

Comment: @leon Yes, upon viewing source of page, I can see code. @Marc I can't seem to find the logs? I went to .ini file and found that logs suppose to go to C:/windows/temp/php_logs (or roughly that), but I can't seem to find it?

Comment: @mfonda I tried to set display_errors = on but when I try to save the file I am denied access?

Comment: @Mr_Crypt: The webserver's logs, not PHP's logs.

Comment: Thanks, it is parsing PHP correctly now, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the following script somewhere within your document root.  Then go to that address it should print out a lot of useful information.

```
<?php
  phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: That's actually the problem, it doesn't print anything?

Comment: can you get anything to display on the page?

Comment: If I run:"<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>", the default html file in htdocs, via the web browser: "localhost/" it displays "It works!". However, when I do the same with PHP file, it just displays raw code. Should it be parsing the code or should it only do that when you access it via filepath (displays nothing).

Comment: if windows this link may help http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml

Comment: I am willing to bet that either Apache does not know how to find your php installation, or you need to restart Apache for your changes to take effect (I only mention it just in case you didn't think of it)

Comment: Working through resetting-up php, see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I added LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll" to the httpd file, but apache won't startup with this line?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is obviously (from the comments) that of a web server setting: you php pages are not being processed.

Try instead this

```
<html><body>
Hi
<br>
<?php
  echo "This line comes from php";
?>
<br>
Bye
</body></html>
```

When you see three lines in your browser, then you know that you PHP pages are being processed. After then, try the `phpinfo()` and only after then try to connect to the database. Step by step...